# Booting Ubuntu from USB on Zotac Zbox HD

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, bios

I successfully made bootable USB with Ubuntu 14.04. I've already tried it on couple of computers, and it works perfectly. Because I want to boot Ubuntu on these PCs just time from the time, I don't want to change boot priority in BIOS. Instead, on startup screen, I hit F12 (or equivalent) and PC lets me to choose from which hardware I want to boot OS.

The problem is that on other computer, Zotac Zbox HD, I was not able to get into this boot menu. I've tried hit ESC, F1, F2, F11, F12, Del, but none of them worked. Not that I just wasn't able to get into boot menu, but not even into BIOS. Strange thing is that there's no screen that tells you what you have to press in order to open BIOS or something like that - after pressing start button, for few seconds there's blank screen, then on 2 seconds there's Zotac logo and after that Windows 7 loading screen. **My question is - when and what I have to hit in order to access either BIOS or Boot menu.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i've realize this:

- To enter BIOS, you need to press DELETE
- To enter Boot menu, you need to press F8

Also, you need to press them repeatedly after you press start button at cold start.